# How to call the method of an anonymous class when the anonymous class is passed as a parameter to the class method of a normal class?

Tags: php, oop, fatal-error, php-7, anonymous-class

I'm using **PHP 7.1.11**

I've tried following code for an Anonymous Class which is declared as a parameter to a class method. I want to call the method present in an anonymous class. But I'm getting a fatal error. How should I call the anonymous class method successfully?

```
<?php

class Util {

    private $logger;

    public function __construct(){} 

    public function getLogger($logger) {    
        $this->logger = $logger;
    }

    public function setLogger($logger) { 

        $this->logger = $logger;
    }
}

$util = new Util();

  $util->setLogger(new class {
    public function log($msg) {
      echo $msg;
    }
  });

  $util->setLogger()->log('Phil runs very fast'); // Ioutput should be : Phil runs very fast
?>
```

Output I'm currently getting :

```
Fatal error: Uncaught ArgumentCountError: Too few arguments to function Util::setLogger(), 0 passed in anonymous_class_ex.php on line 27 and exactly 1 expected in anonymous_class_ex.php:13 Stack trace: #0 anonymous_class_ex.php(https://stackoverflow.com/posts/47605127/edit27): Util->setLogger() #1 {main} thrown in anonymous_class_ex.php on line 13
```

Answer (score 0):

You'd run it like you would any dynamic reference to a callable, as a two-element array: `[object, 'methodName']`. Here the `object` is your anonymous class definition:

```
$util->setLogger([new class {
    public function log($msg) {
        echo $msg;
    }
}, 'log']);
```

Here's a [stand-alone runnable example](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/c86777c44c9950987dc0ad6a72976c1aa40a40e6) for you to look at:

```
class Outer {


    function runner(){
        $this->runCallback([new class {
            function anonymousClassMethod(){
                echo "hi from anonymous class method";
            }
        }, 'anonymousClassMethod']);
    }

    function runCallback(callable $f){
        $f();
    }

}

$o = new Outer();

$o->runner();
```

Comment: Ah gotcha. But "he method setLogger() should return me the object of an anonymous class"... no it doesn't. It doesn't return anything. Look at your code. Anyway. your *`getLogger`* method does return it. You should be using that in your calling code in the second call, not `setLogger`. As @Badshah points out: yer just calling the wrong method.

Answer (score 0):

I see 2 issues with your code.

1. **You are not using the right method on $util**

Instead of 
`$util->setLogger()->log('Phil runs very fast');`
your code should be `$util->getLogger()->log('Phil runs very fast');`.
You want to **get**Logger since it was already set before.

2. **Your implementation of getLogger() might be flawed**

In my opinion, this method should not have any parameter and it should **return** something, which is actually missing in your code.
So instead of

```php
public function getLogger($logger) {    
    $this->logger = $logger;
}
```

you should have something like

```php
public function getLogger() {    
    return $this->logger;
}
```

With those 2 points addressed, your code works as expected. See here for yourself https://ideone.com/V2slho.